# Rolling forward/backward a number of months on a calendar object (JAVA)

Tags: java

I have to create my own calendar class (I know one exists, but we're being tested on our class creating skills, so I can't use any existing methods from the existing calendar class).
One of the methods we have to provide is the ability to roll the Calendar date forward or backwards by a given number of months.

Firstly, my constructor for a Calendar object takes a day, month, and year value. The values are then validated (e.g. makes sure given days is within the number of days in the given month, makes sure months is between 1 and 12).

Now, for the roll back method, I've written this:

```
public void rollMonths(int m) {
    if(month + m > 12){     // Checks if the given months plus the current month will     need to increase the year
        year = year + 1;    // Increases the year by one if it goes over.
        month = m - (12 - month); }     // Finds the number of months till the end of the year, and subtracts this from the given months. Then sets the month to the new value. 
    else if(month + m < 0) {    // Checks if the year will need to be decreased.
        year = year - 1;        // Decreases the year by 1;
        month = 12 - (Math.abs(m) - month); }   // Finds the months between the start of the year and the current month, and subtracts this from the given month value. Then sets the month to this value.
    else
        month = month + m;  // If current month plus given months is within the same year, adds given months to current month.

}
```

This method works, but only if the calendar doesn't increase by more than one year. For example, if I have a calendar for august 2011, and I roll forward 6 months, I correctly get February 2012. However, if I try to roll forward 20 months, the month becomes 16..
Similarly for when I try to roll back a given number of months. I get a correct answer when rolling back within one year.

Sorry if that didn't seem to make sense, I'm not too sure how to explain it. If it doesn't let me know and I'll try to write a better explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly a homework, so i'll just point out the flaw...

Here's you're problem

```
if(month + m > 12){     // Checks if the given months plus the current month will     need to increase the year
        year = year + 1;    // Increases the year by one if it goes over.
        month = m - (12 - month); }
```

You're incrementing year by just `1` year, no matter how many months we are adding...it could be 20,40 or whatever...

Years will increase by `m/12` and months will increase by whatever is left after subtracting the years.

Hint: You'll need to use the `Mod` operator.

Comment: Ok, this is the change that I have made:

    public void rollMonths(int m) {
        if(month + m > 12){     // Checks if the given months plus the current month will need to increase the year
            year = year + m/12;    // Increases the year  if it goes over.
            month = m%12; } 

Is my use of mod correct? Also, if I change the part that rolls backwards, will using mod still work?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about the code formatting.. It doesn't seem to work for me. I indent by four spaces, yes?

Comment: @kumalh, look at bdares second part of the answer.

Comment: If you want to know if your code works correctly, test it.  ;->

(And you will find problems.  Hint:  "m mod 12" will result in a value between zero and 11, inclusive.  Hint:  There are other problems with that change too.)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use implementations of Calendar such as GregorianCalendar.

You need a loop to keep the month number valid.  Something like this:

```
month += m;
while(month < 1){
    month += 12;
    year -= 1;
}
while(month > 12){
    month -= 12;
    year += 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do it in one go:

```
month += m;
if(month < 1)
    year -=1;
if(month > 12 || month < 1){
    month = month % 12 + 1;
    year += month / 12;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the use of '+=' and '-='? I haven't come across that before.

Comment: Would month += m be the same as writing month = month + m?

Comment: @kumalh that's correct.  The notation also works with %, *, /, |, &

Comment: Ahh thank's for that. Makes a lot less typing!

Now my next problem is that I have to take the number of days per month in to consideration. So say you were on the 31st of jan and you wanted to roll forward one month, how would I recognise that February only has 28 days and to change the day to that?

Comment: Now you have a requirements question:  If you have January 31st and you move one month forward (and it's not a leap year), should the answer be February 28th or March 3rd?  Your implementation will be different, depending on which result you want.

Comment: I'd probably keep an array of days in a month for each month (12 integers), and decide if it's a leap year or not with the pretty simple rules: leap year if divisible by 4, but not by 100, but then again if divisible by 400.